# css in firefox and ie is rendering old css file...chrome shows new css just fine

Tags: css

For some reason I can't get the new css to be used in firefox or ie's browser.

I am using php to consolidate all the css into one file, then output it like so:

PHP file:

```
header('Content-type: text/css');
readfile('layout.css');
readfile('a.css'); //jqueryUI
```

Here's how I call it from the HTML side:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='stylesheet/css.php?v=1327523109' type='text/css'   />
```

The "v" querystring parameter is simply a php time() function from a tip I got on another search for the problem.  Hoping the time() would trick the browser into not loading the cache version, but it is not working and still loading the old css.

When I look in firebug's css file it shows the old css file.  However if I directly access the .css page through the url, the output to the browser screen shows all the new css code.

if I render the same page in the chrome browser it shows the new css without any problem...but ie and ff show the old css.

I don't understand what's going on and how to fix it.  Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried CTRL+F5, Clearing the cache, rebooting...none of that worked right.  Then I decided to change the ordering inside the css.php file for the readfile() functions.  Once I moved the ordering around it triggered the new css to load.  I don't know exactly why this worked, but now the new css loaded.

Decided to answer this here in case someone else comes accross a similar problem and the traditional cache clearing doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>del</kbd>  In both browser will allow you to clear your cache, cookies, temp files, and more via nice checkboxes.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the css file is cached in the browser. Try CTRL+F5. If that doesn't work try clearing the cache, if that doesn't work try a reboot. :D

Comment: Rebooting seems to be the magical key in Windows. Somehow, everyone recommends to reboot Windows when someone runs in trouble :p

Answer (score 0):

Here is the trick, instead version, just use the PHP *filemtime()* Function to show your last modified file.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='stylesheet/css.php?<?php filemtime('stylesheet/css.php'?>' type='text/css'   />
```

So every time you modified CSS file, the browser will know what file must be loaded.

hope it help..